# How to set notation for vsCode code generation

Tags: java, code-generation, visual-studio-code

I use Java Extension Pack for vsCode and want to generate getters and setters through `right click->Source Action->Generate Getters and Setters`, but the code is generated based on a wrong notation. For example instead of `public String getName()` it generated `public String get_name()`. I did not find any setting responsible for this in `Settings->Extensions->Java->Code Generation`. How can I change the notation?

Comment: i could not reproduce your issue,it generated the correct method `getName` for me,maybe you could try to use [TypeScript's Getters and Setters Object Oriented Programming Style](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Wilson-Godoi.wg-getters-and-setters) if you could not fix it.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT, I have a Python extension which, probably, affects on the generated code. But the thing is that I use extensions for several languages and want to switch between them. I believe there should be a setting for it, but where? Maybe I have to specify it a config or an environment variable?

Comment: switch the different  languages,you could refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_changing-the-language-for-the-selected-file)